# Path For PHP getimagesize() Function

Tags: php, path, getimagesize

For getimagesize(), what is the proper path to use for the file? In my case, I prefer an absolute path but it gives an error that there is no file but when I give it a full URL, no errors but no output either. The images show but not the attributes from getimagesize().

To clarify, the images are stored in a database with a script pulling them out and providing the headers which, in this case, is doing so from within a foreach loop as it is pulling out multiple images for a dynamic menu. I've done this successfully in the past on other sites and this code is from one of those working sites so not sure why it won't work here!

The question is, what is the proper path type and why no output?

This (preferred) gives errors of no image:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("/internals/viewers/show_image.php?ID=$MenuImage");
$imagetags = (!empty($attr)) ? $attr : "";
```

This does not but no attributes either:

```
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("http://domain.loc/internals/viewers/show_image.php?ID=$MenuImage");
$imagetags = (!empty($attr)) ? $attr : "";
```

Images being displayed using:

```
echo "$MenuLink<img src=\"/internals/viewers/show_image.php?ID=$MenuImage\" alt=\"$MenuName\" title=\"$MenuDescription\" class=\"MenuTab\"$imagetags></a>\n";
```

Here is show_image.php:

```
<?php include $_SERVER ['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/internals/configuration/common.php";

$ImageID = (isset($_GET['ID'])) ? $_GET['ID'] : "";

if (!$ImageID) die ("No image");

    $sqlImage = "SELECT Image, ImageFormat FROM images WHERE ID='$ImageID'";
    $rowImage = DBConnect($sqlImage, "Select", $siteDB);

if (!empty($rowImage)) :
    $mime_type = $rowImage['ImageFormat'];
    $SiteImage = $rowImage['Image'];
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Content-type: image/$mime_type");
    echo $SiteImage;
    imagedestroy($SiteImage);
endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're running this on Linux or MacOS, starting a path with `/` starts it at the *root of the entire hard drive*. Because PHP runs server-side, it doesn't know where the root of your web server directory is. It would be better to use something like `/opt/apache/htdocs/internals/viewers` (just an example), or a relative path. I generally use relative paths.

***EDIT:*** You can try using `getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "internals/viewers/show_image.php?ID=$MenuImage")`, which will likely work in your case.

***ANOTHER EDIT:*** Because your image isn't actually an image file, you can pass an `http://` or `https://` URL into your `getimagesize()` call. Here's an example: `getimagesize("http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/internals/viewers/show_image.php?ID=$MenuImage");`

Comment: Yes, running Ubuntu 19.10 and PHP 7.4. Unfortunately that is one of the many things I did try but it didn't work either, nor did it work when I hard-coded the full path. As for the / starting at the server's root, typically starting a *link* with a slash begins it at the **site's** root folder rather than the server's but nothing I found was clear if that also applied to using a path in a function so thank you for clarifying.

Comment: It just occurred to me that loading it with the full path to the server's root would likely not work as this is not an actual image file but rather it is a PHP script that pulls out the image from the database leaving a URL as the only option. However, while there are no errors, it also does not pull up the values even though the same URL does show the image in the browser.

Comment: Yes, my original answer wouldn't work. I've updated it (see "Another Edit" above) to fit your needs. I hope this helps!

Comment: That was one of the many things I also tried but no results either. Loading the exact same URL into the browser by itself does pull up the images and they also show on the site but I can’t seem to fetch the attributes!

Comment: Should the image data be processed or encoded in same way that it is not currently doing after being fetched from the database and before the headers are applied?

Comment: Although getimagesize() is not working with my database-contained images, I accepted the answer because it was the answer to what I asked as to what the path should be.